# If value == 1 then get the next value in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var countries = [1,"DK",2,"USA",3,"Sweden",];
var languages = [2,"EN",3,"Swedish",1,"Danish"];
var population = [2,"300000000",1,"6000000",3,"8000000"];
```

In javascript, is there a way to look for a value in an array, for example if the value is 1, then take the next value in the array. Here it would be `DK`, `Danish` and `6000000`.

I have this but think it should be way to do it more simple

```
for(var i = 1 ; i < countries.length; i = i+2){
var countryName = countries[i];
var countryId =  countries[i-1];
for(var j = 0; j < languages.length; j = j+2){
    if(languages[j] == countryId){
        var positionSpokenLanguage = j + 1;
        var spokenLanguage = languages[positionSpokenLanguage];
    }
    if(population[j] == countryId){
        var positionPopulation = j + 1;
        var totalPopulation = population[positionPopulation];
    }
}
var message = "In "+countryName+" people speak "+spokenLanguage+
                            " and there are "+totalPopulation+" inhabitatns";

console.log(message);
```

}

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Apart from the language itself, you can simply iterate through each array. Data organization is important if you want to speed up the process and impose some additional conditions. Give it a try and show us.

Comment: I have done this:
for(var i = 1 ; i < countries.length; i = i+2){
 var countryName = countries[i];
 var countryId =  countries[i-1];
 for(var j = 0; j < languages.length; j = j+2){
  if(languages[j] == countryId){
   var positionSpokenLanguage = j + 1;
   var spokenLanguage = languages[positionSpokenLanguage];
  }
  if(population[j] == countryId){
   var positionPopulation = j + 1;
   var totalPopulation = population[positionPopulation];
  }
 }
 var message = "In "+countryName+" people speak "+spokenLanguage+
        " and there are "+totalPopulation+" inhabitatns";

 console.log(message);
}

Comment: But I think there should be a shorter way to write it

Comment: @ThomasHansen edit your answer rather than put code into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As you are actually looking for a value in every other item in the array, there is no built in method for that.

If you know that the value is in the array, you can just loop until you find it:

```
var index = 0;
while (countries[index] != 1) index += 2;
var value = countries[index + 1];
```

---

Your data has an unintuitive format, which makes it a bit awkward to work with. If possible you should use a data format where you don't mix keys with values, for example an object:

```
var countries = { 1: "DK", 2: "USA", 3: "Sweden" };
```

Then you can just get the value using the key:

```
var value = countries[1];
```